# Flink JobGraph Submission

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to compile the given SQL into Flink's Job Graph and want to submit to YARN.

```
JobGraph jobGraph = streamExecutionEnv.getStreamGraph().getJobGraph();

YarnDeployer().deployJob(jobGraph);
```

`YarnDeployer` is custom class which uses `YarnClusterDescriptor` and `ClusterSpecification` API of Flink to submit the job.

In EMR, I started Flink YARN session and submitted job using flink run.

I am getting below error :
The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call `execute()` on the execution environment.

is it possible to run the JobGraph with out execute? I don't want to run continuous jobs.

Comment: I think you must call env.execute() or the stream job will not execute

Comment: I am looking at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-yarn-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/yarn/YARNITCase.java as reference

Comment: Please give us more information: What source(e) are you using; what are you trying to avoid; and why aren't you using batch rather than streaming?

Comment: FYI, Flink 1.10 introduces new interfaces for job submission and related activities. See https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/02/11/release-1.10.0.html#unified-logic-for-job-submission.

Comment: I have mix of batch sources and streaming sources. If I run continuous jobs using execute, each job would be running  separately and I may not be able scale. Also, if there are no messages from streaming source, containers would be running idle. What I am thinking is periodically, submit the SQL job to YARN.